# Android OpenCV - Eye Closure Detection

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing

Tutorial : http://romanhosek.cz/android-eye-detection-and-tracking-with-opencv/

I used this tutorial to detect eyes and face of a person. But my question is, how to use this given sample code to detect eye closure. For example, to detect open and closed state of a eye. Can anyone give me some codes to do this.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have the eye position in the frame, you can use a binary classifier (such as SVM) to classify whether the image region containing the eye is considered open or shut.
In order to train this classifier, you will need to collect a set of images, manually provide ground truth (supervised learning) and then train the classifier.

Comment: can you provide some examples and related web articles or tutorials to do this task 

Thank you :)

Comment: This is a very broad topic, but perhaps start with a simple search and read:  https://www.google.com/search?q=svm+image+classification

Comment: Thanks I'll try your method. If someone have any codes related to android eye closure detection. Please share with me :)